# A java library of common unix commands (specifically dd)?

Tags: java, unix, dd

I need to use the dd command for blocking some files, and would rather do it without calling it via shell.

Is there a class library already written, or should I roll my own blocker unblocker?

Basically equivalent to going:

```
dd if=foo.log of=fooblocked.log cbs=79 conv=block
```

Comment: By the way. I don't think Runtime.getRuntime().exec()  use shell.

Comment: Kk noted. But would rather use pure Java.

Comment: You cannot use pure Java as this is an OS specific facility that the virtual machine does not know about. At some point you will need to interact with  the underlying OS. Your choices are using a shell command or calling the unix C library via JNI (yuck!).

Comment: I mean just reading the file in and manipulating the bytes in Java, rather then calling dd. I.e. rewriting dd conv=block. I have it working, but it's buggy and would like a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` executes the command passed in a shell (a command prompt in Windows) the shell defaults to the programs working directory.

```
try {
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     String str = br.readLine();
     while(str!=null) {
         System.out.println(str);
         str=br.readLine();
     }
}
```

If you need the program to wait until the command completes, you can use  `p.waitFor()`.